# Python doesn't always continue for-loop with items added from within loop

Tags: python, for-loop

In this example, the for-loop will detect the new item and continues

```py
array = [6,7]
for i, n in enumerate(array):
    print(array)
    if i == 1:
        array.append(1)
```

But in my solution to this [kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5531abe4855bcc8d1f00004c/train/python), the item is successfully added within loop but loop doesn't continue

```py
def bowling_score(frames):
    score = 0
    frames = frames.split(" ")
    multipliers = [1,1,1,1]
    roll = 0
    for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
        print(i)
        if "X" in frame:
            score += 10 * multipliers[roll]
            multipliers[roll+1] += 1 if i < 9 else 0
            multipliers[roll+2] += 1 if i < 9 else 0
            if i >= 9 and len(frame) > 1:
                frames = frames + [frame[1:]]
                print(frames)
        elif "/" in frame:
            score += int(frame[0]) * multipliers[roll]
            score += (10-int(frame[0])) * multipliers[roll+1]
            multipliers[roll+2] += 1 if i < 9 else 0
            if i >= 9 and len(frame) > 1:
                frames = frames + [frame[2:]]
        else:
            score += int(frame[0]) * multipliers[roll]
            print(f"len of frame = {len(frame)}")
            score += int(frame[1]) * multipliers[roll+1]
        roll += len(frame)
        multipliers = multipliers + [1]*len(frame)
    return score

print(bowling_score('X X X X X X X X X XXX'))
```

ChatGPT has been unhelpful

> This behavior isn't clearly documented in Python's official
> documentation, and it's indeed surprising, considering that Python
> usually allows list modification during iteration. It might be related
> to some specific optimization in Python's for loop implementation.
> Nonetheless, the recommendation remains the same: generally, it's best
> to avoid modifying a list while iterating over it, because the
> behavior can be surprising and unintuitive.
>
> To handle this in your bowling_score function, you can use a different
> type of loop that doesn't have this edge case, such as a while loop.

Comment: You should never modify the list you're iterating through exactly because it results in unpredictable behaviour just like you see here. ChatGPT is being perfectly on point.

Comment: Your problem is not clear [ask] and [mre], besides I agree with above, this is a well-known No-No.

Comment: Your takeaway should be that "behaviour is not well defined" is the the way a software developer says "you should not do this".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop over the array is constructed with the original array, and adding element within the loop leads to unpredictable behavior as noted.

You just need to replace your `for` loop with a `while` loop like:

```py
array = [6,7]
i = 0
while len(array) > i:
    print(array)
    if i == 1:
        array.append(1)
    i += 1
```

If you need to access elements of the array at the point in the loop, just look it up by index with `array[i]`